# Select Distinct Row data in multiple occurrences

Tags: sql-server

I have this table

visitID      visitRel       visitorID
1                   0                              14
2                    1                              14
3                    0                              15
4                    0                              16
5                    1                              17
6                    0                              17

I would like to select only visitorID that have only one  value which is 0,not like visitorID that has both 0 and 1 like visitorID 14 and 17.

Comment: You're going to need to use a having clause and a distinct on visitRel.

Comment: [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for asking, i only need the VisitorsID that have only one occurence of 0 but not both occurence of 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sum them up:

```
create table #t (visitID int, visitRel  int, visitorID int)
insert #t values
(1,         0,                 14),
(2,         1,                 14),
(3,         0,                 15),
(4,         0,                 16),
(5,         1,                 17),
(6,         0,                 17)


select visitorid
from #t
group by visitorid
having sum(visitrel)=0
```

Comment: What happens if VisitRel allows mroe than 0,1 such as a 2?

Comment: @xQbert Why would it matter? The op is only interested in visitors "that have only 0". This is why you downvoted? :)

Comment: @xQbert you ar thinking beyond, the values are only 1 and 0.

Comment: Please edit the question with the new schema and sample data, or open a new question altogether.

Comment: @Dean please  try using sum(visitrel)=1 it picks 17 and 14 is there something iam missing